# Crait's icy surface with red substance beneath

Tags: plot-explanation, star-wars, the-last-jedi

In *Star Wars:The Last Jedi* rebellion hides on planet Crait which was an old base of rebellion when they had conflicts with Darth Vader.

We can see this same planet in second installment of *star wars* franchise *Empire Strikes Back* but in that movie planet is just one icy planet but in *The Last Jedi* we can see red material hidden beneath icy surface which is reveal when some one walk on surface that is not the case in *Empire Strikes Back*.

Why this change happened to the planet?

Comment: Except it wasn't ice, it was salt. This is literally said in the movie.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### This is not the same planet as in *Empire Strikes Back*.

The planet in *Star Wars: The Last Jedi* is called [Crait](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Crait), but the planet shown in Episode V is called [Hoth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoth).

Though, both are different ones. Since the planet Crait is called old base of Rebel Alliance in the movie and Hoth was abandoned after the encounter between rebels and Darth Vader, I can understand the confusion here.

And the white substance on Crait is not ice, but salt.

> **Soldier:** (tastes the soil) **Salt!**

Comment: ohk I got confused here thank you @AJ for your clarifiction.

Comment: I remembered that scene when soldier taste the soil and I thought that that material is salt mixed with some red material covered with ice